# When will we judge that the software which we made are in 1.x version, or 2.x version?

Tags: programming-practices

For example, i have made a software for someone. Regularly, i will update my application sometime for fixing bug reason, adding some function, or remove some function, etc. After that, i will list what i changed so far for my application and added that to my changelog list.

First, i will named my application as "Application 1.0". A few days later i got some bug or missing function in my app. I tried to fixing the bugs ASAP. After that i confused what should i named my application ? "Application 1.1" or "APplication 2.0" ? Is there any requirement before named our application as "2.x" or "1.1.x" ? or it's just from my own decision ?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning

Comment: Why i got domvoyed?

Comment: I hate it when domvoying happens.

Comment: misspelled it :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For application software, the versioning is a little bit arbitrary. The rule of thumb is:

- For bug correction, change the third number, generally called the patch level. However,
- If you introduce some additional functionality or make improvements, change the second number instead (minor version number). However,
- If you introduce major changes and breakthrough improvements, go for a major version (aka 2.0.0)

The difference between major and minor is not always clear, and is sometimes driven by marketing. Although I do not recommend these practices, here some real life examples:

- if annual maintenance fees cover new minor versions free of charge, but you've invested a lot in some additional development, claim that it's a major change, so to relaunch the cash machine.
- if you've a bright version that you've just made a little brighter (so should be minor revision) but your main competitor is two major versions ahead, just align your major version so to be at least as high. If you have to skip a major version, don't worry, just find some excuses for the PR.

If you're looking for good guidance, you can adopt [**semantic versioning**](https://semver.org).  It is very precisely defined and largely adopted. Its scope is however limited to API, with the aim to allow better dependency management.  But you can generalise it for your application software by considering not only programming interface but also user interface.

Comment: ideally, breaking changes should only happen in major versions.

Answer (score 0):

Version numbering has never been well defined, and varies between developers, so what follows is necessarily approximate.

Older software generally used an x.yy format. The first number was a major release, while the second number was sub-releases. This was usually a true decimal with two numbers after the point. Every time you change the software you add .01 to the number, or go up to the next .10 division for a bigger change. For really minor tweaks or bug fixes, you might go up by 0.001 instead (e.g. 0.992->0.993). The number before the decimal changes when you feel you're making a significant change, that - in commercial software - you'd charge for. In this system 1.9 is a later version than 1.10 and things hit asymptotic difficulties as you approach 2.0. Version 0.yy is reserved for beta, or other pre-release versions. 1.00 is your first attempt at a master, or release, version.

It is now increasingly common to use a x.y.z numbering system, where x is the major number, y is the minor number, and z is a patch or build number. Significant changes increment y, whilst bug fixes or insignificant tweaks increment z. When you change x you zero y and z again, and when you change y you zero z. Incrementing x still indicates a major release with new, possibly backwardly incompatible, changes. In this scheme 1.10.1 is a later release than 1.9.7.

And then there's Knuth [who asymptotically versions TeX towards Pi](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-TeXfuture.html) - Which is cute but hardly the most generally useful scheme - and companies like Microsoft who randomly alter their numbering schemes every couple of project.

I strongly recommend using an x.y.z scheme for new software, and the semantic versioning scheme for libraries.